# Почему разработчики коллекций java так решили?

Tags: java, наследование, коллекции, интерфейс

В интерфейсе Collection, есть метод size(). Есть так же интерфейс List, который наследуется от Collection, при этом, зная, что при наследовании интерфейсов, мы знаем что все методы родителя уже грубо говоря, являются частью предка. Т.е. при public interface List extends Collection, метод size() из Collection уже есть и у List, однако, покапавшись в исходниках, я обнаружил что несмотря на то что в Collection есть метод size(), его все равно реализуют в List (в самом интерфейсе пишут этот метод(int size())).

Зачем это сделали разработчики языка, если такой метод уже есть у Collection, и при этом List от него наследуется?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю если смотреть на java docs
 то можно увидеть разницу читая эти интерфейсы.

```
/**
 * Returns the number of elements in this list.  If this list contains
 * more than {@code Integer.MAX_VALUE} elements, returns
 * {@code Integer.MAX_VALUE}.
 *
 * @return the number of elements in this list
 */
 int size();
```

и

```
/**
 * Returns the number of elements in this collection.  If this collection
 * contains more than {@code Integer.MAX_VALUE} elements, returns
 * {@code Integer.MAX_VALUE}.
 *
 * @return the number of elements in this collection
 */
int size();
```

Причина думаю банальна читая Java Docs для листа не хотелось бы читать слово collection

Comment: Хм, настолько очевидно, что не сразу понятно, спасибо большое!))

Comment: @ksharlen Если ответ устроил пометить не забудьте.

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле, метода нет ни у `Collection`, ни у `List` - это лишь интерфейсы. `List` наследуется от `Collection`, следовательно, для `List` также требуется данный метод.
В случае если бы были реализации методов, то перегрузка была бы вполне оправдана - как правило `List` всегда знает свой размер в виде числа, а вот `Collection` в общем виде не совсем (нечто подобное есть в .NET)

Comment: Я что-то не понял. Так метод есть или нет? "На самом деле, метода нет" читаю дальше для "List также требуется данный метод"

Comment: Ой, имею ввиду нет реализации ведь это интерфейсы. Если класс реализует `List`, который в свою очередь наследуется от `Collection`, то все требования `Collection` также будут действовать и таким образом "добавятся" к требованиям `List`. Семантической нагрузки от того что мы продублируем заголовок функции в дочернем интерфейсе нет, разве что для документации (как Вы и заметили выше).